# Updating dataframe in spark/scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I need to update value of dataframe column based on a string that isn't part of any other column in the dataframe. How do I do this?

For e.g. Let's say my dataframe has column A, B, C. I want to update value of column C based on combination of value in column A & a static string. I tried to do the following.

```
val df = originalDF.withColumn("C", Helper.dudf(df("A"), lit("str")))
```

My helper class as following

```
val addDummyColumn :(String, String)=>String=(input:String, recordType: String)=>{input}

val dummyUDF = udf(addDummyColumn)
```

My UDF that takes in variable A & recordType:

```
if(recordType.equals("TRANSACTION") {
 if(A > 0 ) return "CHARGE";
   else return "REFUND"
} else if (recordType.equals("CHARGEBACK") {
    return "CHARGEBACK"
}
```

Example Input & Output:

```
Sample Input:
A=10, recordType=TRANSACTION
Output: C = CHARGE
A=-10, recordType=TRANSACTION
C = REFUND

A=10, recordType=CHARGEBACK
C = CHARGEBACK
```

My problem is that withColumn only accepts Column so I did lit("str") but I don't know how to extract value of that column in my UDF. Ideas?

Comment: Can you add sample input and expected output?

Comment: can you elaborate what do you mean by `I want to update value of column C based on combination of value in column A & a static string` with an example?

Comment: I've updated the question with an example.

Comment: Do you also pass the `recordType as lit("TRANSACTION")` or is this another column

Comment: @ShankarKoirala I pass it as lit("TRANSACTION")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If *column A* is a *IntegerType* then you can define the `udf` function as

```
val recordType: String = //"TRANSACTION" or "CHARGEBACK"
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
val dummyUDF = udf((A: Int, recordType: String) => {
  if(recordType.equals("TRANSACTION")){
    if(A > 0) "CHARGE" else "REFUND"
  } else if (recordType.equals("CHARGEBACK"))
    "CHARGEBACK"
  else
    "not known"
})

val df = originalDF.withColumn("C", dummyUDF(originalDF("A"), lit(recordType)))
```

Comment: I don't intend to concat(will update my question). I just want to use value of A and the static string in my UDF to come up with a value for column C.

Comment: The static string needs to be passed from within the withColumn call.

Comment: sure checking. Quick question: You pass in lit(recordType) to UDF but you take it in as recordType: String. Do the casting from Column to String happen automatically?

Comment: udf functions work row by row, serializing and deserializing the values passed to udf function. Since lit(recordType) is of StringType column, it will get converted to String primitive type when passed to udf function.

Answer (score 1):

This is how you can use `udf` and pass the columns and static strings

```
 val addDummy = udf((A : String, recordType: String) => {
if(recordType.equals("TRANSACTION")) {
  if(A.toInt > 0 ) 
    "CHARGE" 
  else
    "REFUND"
}else if (recordType.equals("CHARGEBACK")) {
  "CHARGEBACK"
}else
  "NONE"
  })
```

Now call the `udf` as below

```
val newDF = df.withColumn("newCol", addDummy($"A", lit("TRANSACTION")))
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: could this "newCol" be the existing col "C"? I see you are passing lit("dummy") to your UDF but your UDF has String as input paramteres. How does that work?

Comment: thanks. Yes I just tested and it works but I had to choose the other answer as it came first and also explained how the serialization/deserialization worked.

Comment: Ok great. Glad the answer helped you